# How can I apply for US visa from Montreal (target to tour NYC)?

Tags: b1-b2-visas, filipino-citizens, montreal

I'm from the Philippines and will have a project assignment in Montreal for 3 years. Can I apply for US visa there? how? I'd like to cross to NYC for a few days tour.

Comment: Will you be on a work visa in Montreal or a permanent residence ?

Comment: @blackbird57 why would that make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a long term visa or a permanent residence status in Canada, you can apply for a visitor visa from Montreal at the US consulate general. A friend of mine who lived here on a work visa was able to apply for a visitor visa a few years ago.

The State Department's [website](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visitor.html#overview) doesn't mention any requirement where you can apply, other than your place of permanent residence.

> You must schedule an appointment for your visa interview, generally,
>   at the U.S. Embassy or Consulate in the country where you live. You
>   may schedule your interview at any U.S. Embassy or Consulate, but be
>   aware that it may be difficult to qualify for a visa outside of your
>   place of permanent residence.

The rest of the application is the same formality anywhere and you can do most of it online. You can see all their requirements [here](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visitor.html#overview)

Comment: i will be on a work visa

Comment: Applying in the place of residence is not a requirement, as the quoted material makes clear.